# rails server でデータベースが作成されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails初心者です。
環境はWindows7 32bit、ruby 2.3.3、Rails 5.1.5、sqlite3 1.3.13 x86-mingw32　です。

rails serverを実行すると、下記メッセージが表示されます。

```
C:\pg\data\books>rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.5 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.11.2 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Love Song
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

localhost:3000 へアクセスすると下記画面は表示されます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ただ、コード実行時に、エラーメッセージが表示されているとおり、
データベースが作成されていません。
dbディレクトリに　development.sqlite3　が作成されません。

どのように解決すればよいでしょうか。宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「エラーメッセージが表示されているとおり」の具体的な内容を質問を編集して追記してください

Comment: 申し訳ありません。具体的にはメッセージに
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
と出ているので、シグナルが・・・すいません、エラーなのは分かるのですが、内容が分かりません。

Answer (score 2):

`*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!`
上記のエラーは利用しているOS（おそらくWindows）では`USR2`などのシグナルを利用していないために発生しています。
このエラーはデータベースには関係せず、Pumaの再起動やログファイルの再生成が不可能になる程度ですので、`Ctrl-C`で落としてもう一度`rails server`で起動するような運用ならば特に問題はないかと思います。

データベースの作成は`rails server`ではできないので、以下のコマンドを試してみてください。
`bundle exec rake db:create; bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: アプリサーバの起動と停止は、rails serverで起動し、Ctrl-Cで落とすという方法でやりますので、問題ありません。
また、データベース作成は、上記コマンド実行で作成できました。サイトrubylifeで勉強をしているのですが、そこにはrails server起動で自動的にデータベースが作成されると書かれていたので、困っていました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @ticktuck 誰かが回答してくれて、問題が解決した場合には、質問の承認をお願いできますか? システム的に、問題が解決済みであることを示すことができます。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers